# Rails 3 has_one association: unlink associated object without destroying it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have two classes, `Master` and `Slave`. The `Master` class has_one `slave`, the `Slave` class belongs to `master`.

Given two associated objects, `master_a` and `slave_a` (where `slave_a` belongs to `master_a`), how can I unlink them without destroying `slave_a` from the database? I essentially need to "free-up" `slave_a`. I've tried `master_a.slave.delete`, which destroys `slave_a` from the database.

I've also tried `master_a.slave.update_attribute(:master_id, nil)`, but next time `master_a.save` is called, it relinks them. Is this indicative of a callback I'm overlooking (of which the Master class has quite a few), or am I just using the wrong tool for the job?

*Edit*: I should have specified, I do not want to destroy either object, only the link between these two particular instances. Also, the real models are not actually called master and slave, that's just an illustrative example I'm using.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do?  If deleting then Austintacious' solution will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because of the way the `master` and `slave` object is held in memory.  Even though you've updated the slave, the master still thinks the slave is associated with it as the associated slave object is still held in memory (this is usually more efficient).  When the master is reloaded, the association will disappear.  So, if you did this in the console you'd expect to see something like this:

```
master = Master.find(123)
=> <master object>
master.slave.update_attribute(:master_id, nil)
=> true
master.slave
=> <slave object>
master.reload 
OR
master = Master.find(123)
master.slave
=> nil
```

Comment: I managed to resolve this by doing both `master.slave.update_attribute(:master_id, nil)` and `master.slave = nil` before `master.save` gets called.