# Rails preferred way of setting foreign_key to nil on child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `has_one` relationship with `Device` and `Car`.

What's the preferred way with `ActiveRecord` for removing the child from the parent (setting the `device_id` nil on the `car` but NOT deleting the `car` itself)?

When the `device.car = nil` line runs it gets committed immediately to the database. I want it to be committed only on save and return some useful error if it doesn't get saved.

I know I could also try to lookup the `car`, set the `dongle_id` to `nil` and save that, but this action is rather about the `device` than the `car`.

mutation:

```
def disconnect_car_and_device(id:)
  device = Device.find(id)

  authorize(current_user, device)

  device.car = nil

  if device.save
    { device: device, errors: [] }
  else
    { device: nil, errors: build_errors(device.errors) }
  end
end
```

models:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :car
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :device
end
```

Comment: Are you sure when the device.car = nil line runs it gets committed to database ? 

It will only commit to database when you save the device otherwise it assigned nil value to device object but not in database.

Comment: I thought that would be the case as well. But I was running it in console and when I ran that line it got committed.

Comment: May be this answer will help you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499270/rails-3-has-one-association-unlink-associated-object-without-destroying-it

Comment: `device.car = nil` gets committed to the database because of how `HasOneAssociation` implements the writer method `car=`. There is no way to unlink the association from `Device`, as the attribute that creates the link is located in `Car`.

Answer (score 1):

After trying different ways I found below code to work as expected :

```
def disconnect_car_and_device(id:)
  device = Device.find(id)

  authorize(current_user, device)
  car = device.car

  if device.save && car.update(device: nil)
    { device: device, errors: [] }
  else
    { device: nil, errors: build_errors(device.errors) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def disconnect_car_and_device(id:)
  device = Device.find(id)

  authorize(current_user, device)

  device.transaction do
    device.car = nil

    if device.save
      { device: device, errors: [] }
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      { device: nil, errors: build_errors(device.errors) }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi! It would always be better to leave an explanation to your answer.